# cannot "startActivity" from service while main activity is stopped

Tags: android, service, android-activity, process

In main activity of application I startService:

```
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothService.class).putExtra("address", address));
```

which establish bluetooth connection with PC. Then I press home button on android phone and main activity goes background. I send call command from PC to phone and debug show that service normally recieve that command and trying to call:

```
String[] splits = parameters.split("\\|");
String number = splits[0];

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

but call activity lunched only when I show main activity on screen.

In manifest:

```
<service android:name="BluetoothService" >
```

I tried to use android:process=":newThread" tag, but service crashed in line

```
ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

also I can't debug service when it in different process.

EDITED://///////////////////////////////////

I have a problem, I start activity from simple class:

```
class Command_call_impl implements CommandImpl
{
    public void Execute(String parameters)
    {
        String[] splits = parameters.split("\\|");
        String number = splits[0];

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("phone_number", number);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and can't initialize Intent. Seems eclipse can't recognize MainActivity, but its in the same package.

EDITED:///////////////
I start activity in such way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("phone_number", number);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

but onNewIntent called only when mainActivity is active. I also tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP key.

EDITED://////////////////////

Problem solved after double starting the same activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("phone_number", number);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().getApplication().startActivity(intent);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent2.putExtra("phone_number", number);
    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ConnectionManager.getInstance().GetMainActivity().getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

I think first intent shows activity and the second start call activity. Interesting thing is that if I remove intent.putExtra("phone_number", number) from first intent, its not work. Its very curiously.

Also call not lunched when screen is off.

Comment: Do you try to make a phone call or having MainActivity making a phone call?

Comment: Yes, phone call work when main activity showed in screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Command_call_impl implements CommandImpl
{
private Context mContext;

    public Command_call_impl(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }   

    public void Execute(String parameters)
    {
        String[] splits = parameters.split("\\|");
        String number = splits[0];

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("phone_number", number);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);   
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity override onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phone_number");
    if (phoneNumber != null)
    {
         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
        //callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just sent a command to your service with the number to call and then have the service implements the code above

Comment: is class Command_call_impl implements CommandImpl an inner class in the service class?

Comment: No, class Command_call_impl is simple class. Please see my edit.

Comment: It's not help. The problem solved only after double starting the same activity. See my edit.